# JSF ace: datatable conditional row styling

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces-3

I have jsf page using ACE Datable. I need to color row based on a condition so I'm using rowStyleClass attribute of datatable.

```
<ace:dataTable value="#{bookingListAndEditController.bookingList}"
                           rowStyleClass="#{booking.pickupTime.before(bookingListAndEditController.currentDate)?'jsfcrud_odd_row':null}"
                           var="booking" filterEvent="enter" paginator="true" rows="20" selectionMode="multiple"
                           rowSelectListener="#{bookingListAndEditController.rowSelected}"                           
                           rowUnselectListener="#{bookingListAndEditController.rowUnselected}" stateMap="#{bookingListAndEditController.stateMap}">
```

But It doesn't seems to be working. Could anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: do you wanted to give different color for odd rows?

Answer (score 0):

Always remember, the var `booking` is an object of `bookingList` and is only available for the child elements of `ace:dataTable`. Repeat the styleClass for all the columns so that the style is applied for the whole row and only the row which has booking pickup time less than current time.

```
        <ace:dataTable value="#{bookingListAndEditController.bookingList}" 
                       var="booking" filterEvent="enter" paginator="true" rows="20" selectionMode="multiple"
                       rowSelectListener="#{bookingListAndEditController.rowSelected}"                           
                       rowUnselectListener="#{bookingListAndEditController.rowUnselected}" stateMap="#{bookingListAndEditController.stateMap}">
           <ace:column styleClass="#{booking.pickupTime.before
               (bookingListAndEditController.currentDate)?'jsfcrud_odd_row':''}">
           ..
           </ace:column>

                 .......
           <ace:column styleClass="#{booking.pickupTime.before
               (bookingListAndEditController.currentDate)?'jsfcrud_odd_row':''}">
           ..
           </ace:column>
```

Comment: I don't need to color odd-rows, what I need is to color the row when booking pickup time is less than current time.                               "#{booking.pickupTime.before(bookingListAndEditController.currentDate)?'jsfcrud_odd_row':null}"

Comment: You need to use appropriate naming convention. `jsfcrud_odd_row` indicates you are trying to do something like odd or even !

Comment: Sorry for the confusion to you. I will definitely use a good naming convention next time. I'll try the solution and get back.